# bootstrap4: Correct way to use row and col in this scenario

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4. I want to have a h3 heading and a button below. I can see there are few ways of doing it. I have listed them below

**Method1**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3>Some Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="button">Some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method2** (looks to use too many row col)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button">Some button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method3**

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button">Some button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone guide which is the right way to do this using row and col.

Comment: if u want to stack them ontop of each other u can use them without row and col, otherwise the first method is ok

Comment: I want to do using row and col

Comment: i think u are doing it right

Comment: what about the second method. it looks more generic

Comment: that is way too much nesting, u should avoid that, its unneccessary

Comment: You could simply add the button right after the h3 with a linebreak between or set h3 to 100% width

Comment: updated my question added method3

Comment: you only need 1 `col` since `h3` is `d-block`, which automatically forces the `button` to the next line. if you still want 2 `col`s, then i would go with method 1 since it's simplest. i wouldn't say there's any "correct" way to use grids except to keep the markup readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to have a h3 heading and a button below"

If you have no other requirements and it doesn't need to change responsively the "correct" method is simply..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h3>Some Text</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Some button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Headings are `display:block` so that will automatically force the button to a new line. If you want to use separate columns then **Method 1** is again the best choice because it's the simplest.